# How can I combine the decal shader with particle system in Unity?

Tags: unity, particles, decal-system

I'm using the [decal shader](https://github.com/ColinLeung-NiloCat/UnityURPUnlitScreenSpaceDecalShader) in my project and everything works well until I want to use it in particle system. I set it like below

[image: particle system with the decal shader]

However, there is nothing displaying in the screen.

Basically I just want the particle system to emit decals and if decals hit something(like the plane), it would show main texture's color.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: It's unusual to use particles as decals, so it's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish by doing so. What will this particle system represent in your game?

Comment: A visual effect will be emitted to a uneven surface. If I use a normal particle system, some  parts of it will get into the surface.

Comment: So you want to prevent clipping/interpenetration of particles with the surface? It might be better to ask "how to prevent visible clipping of particles into a surface" instead, and sketch an example of what resulting appearance you want.